# Сериализация сообщения Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, сериализация

Структура сообщения .proto

```
package Queries;

message Authorization
{
    required int32 login = 1;
    required string password = 2;
}

message Query
{
    required int32 type= 1;
    repeated Authorization authorization = 2;
}
```

код программы на C#

```
Queries.Query query = new Queries.Query();
query.type = 1;
Queries.Authorization authorizationMessage = new Queries.Authorization();
authorizationMessage.login = 1;  
authorizationMessage.password = "pass";
query.authorization.Add(authorizationMessage);

Stream streamQuery = new MemoryStream();
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<Queries.Query>(streamQuery, query);
var msg = new byte[streamQuery.Length];
streamQuery.Read(msg, 0, (int)streamQuery.Length);
string text = Encoding.Default.GetString(msg);
log.Debug(text.Length);
log.Debug(text);
```

Сообщения в логах. Вместо пробелов ожидаю увидеть сериализованное сообщение (во втором сообщении 12 пробелов)

```
[Debug]    11/22/2013 11:51:25   12
[Debug]    11/22/2013 11:51:25
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Необходимо добавить перед чтением из потока:

`streamQuery.Position = 0`

В противном случае произойдёт чтение из конца потока `streamQuery`, а метод `streamQuery.Read()` при вызове возвратит 0.

Comment: AlexeyM, спасибо! Теперь работает так как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо добавить строку **streamQuery.Position = 0;** перед чтением из потока. В противном случае произойдёт чтение из конца потока streamQuery, а метод streamQuery.Read() при вызове возвратит 0.